# Numba @jit fails to optimise simple function

Tags: python, numpy, numba

I have a pretty simple function which uses Numpy arrays and for loops, but adding the Numba @jit decorator gives absolutely no speed up:

```
# @jit(float64[:](int32,float64,float64,float64,int32))
@jit
def Ising_model_1D(N=200,J=1,T=1e-2,H=0,n_iter=1e6):
    beta = 1/T
    s = randn(N,1) > 10  
    s[N-1] = s[0]
    mag = zeros((n_iter,1))
    aux_idx =  randint(low=0,high=N,size=(n_iter,1))

    for i1 in arange(n_iter):
        rnd_idx = aux_idx[i1]
        s_1 = s[rnd_idx]*2 - 1
        s_2 = s[(rnd_idx+1)%(N)]*2 - 1
        s_3 = s[(rnd_idx-1)%(N)]*2 - 1
        delta_E = 2.0*J*(s_2+s_3)*s_1 + 2.0*H*s_1

        if(delta_E < 0):
            s[rnd_idx] = np.logical_not(s[rnd_idx]) 
        elif(np.exp(-1*beta*delta_E) >= rand()):
            s[rnd_idx] = np.logical_not(s[rnd_idx])
        s[N-1] = s[0]
        mag[i1] = (s*2-1).sum()*1.0/N 
    return mag
```

MATLAB on the other hand takes less than 0.5 seconds to run this!
Why is Numba missing something so basic?

Comment: You are calling NumPy functions on scalar values in the loop body. These functions are designed to operate efficiently over large arrays, not single values. These function calls cannot be optimised away by numba. In short, you need to vectorise the code, not JIT-compile it.

Comment: @ajcr I think some of them can, actually, like `rand()` and `ndarray.sum()` (at least, they can in the latest version of `numba`).

Comment: @jme:  ah, thanks, I wasn't aware that that was the case. I had thought that repeatedly calling `np.logical_not` (and other compiled functions) would slow down the loop. I ought to dig a little deeper into the numba docs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a reworking of your code that runs in about 0.4 seconds on my machine:

```
def ising_model_1d(N=200,J=1,T=1e-2,H=0,n_iter=1e6):
    n_iter = int(n_iter)
    beta = 1/T
    s = randn(N) > 10
    s[N-1] = s[0]

    mag = zeros(n_iter)
    aux_idx =  randint(low=0,high=N,size=n_iter)

    pre_rand = rand(n_iter)

    _ising_jitted(n_iter, aux_idx, s, J, N, H, beta, pre_rand, mag)

    return mag


@jit(nopython=True)
def _ising_jitted(n_iter, aux_idx, s, J, N, H, beta, pre_rand, mag):
    for i1 in range(n_iter):
        rnd_idx = aux_idx[i1]
        s_1 = s[rnd_idx*2] - 1
        s_2 = s[(rnd_idx+1)%(N)]*2 - 1
        s_3 = s[(rnd_idx-1)%(N)]*2 - 1
        delta_E = 2.0*J*(s_2+s_3)*s_1 + 2.0*H*s_1
        t = rand()
        if delta_E < 0:
            s[rnd_idx] = not s[rnd_idx]
        elif np.exp(-1*beta*delta_E) >= pre_rand[i1]:
            s[rnd_idx] = not s[rnd_idx]

        s[N-1] = s[0]
        mag[i1] = (s*2-1).sum()*1.0/N
```

Please make sure the results are as expected! I changed much of what you had, and can't guarantee that the calculations are correct!

Working with `numba` requires a little care. Python functions, as well as most `numpy` functions, cannot be optimized by the compiler. One thing I find helpful is to use the `nopython` option to `@jit`. This means that the compiler will complain whenever you give it some code that it can't really optimize. You can then look at the error message and find the line that will likely slow down your code.

The trick, I find, is to write a "gateway" function in Python that does as much of the work as possible using `numpy` and its vectorized functions. It should create the empty arrays that you'll need to store the results in. It should package all of the data you'll need during the computation. Then it should pass all of these into your jitted function in one big, long argument list.

Case in point: notice how I handle random number generation in the jitted code. In your original code, you called `rand()`:

```
elif(np.exp(-1*beta*delta_E) >= rand()):
```

But `rand()` can't be optimized by `numba` (in older versions of `numba`, at least. In newer versions it can, provided that `rand` is called without arguments). The observation is that you need a single random number for every one of the `n_iter` iterations. So we simply create a random array using `numpy` in our wrapper function, then feed this random array to the jitted function. Getting a random number is then as simple as indexing into this array.

Lastly, for a list of the `numpy` functions that can be optimized by the latest version of the compiler, see [here](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.21.0/reference/numpysupported.html). In my reworking of your code I was aggressive in removing calls to `numpy` functions so that the code would work over more versions of `numba`.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for the detailed response. The Numba docs are a bit sparse on details.